# Preact setState hook wont work within a setInterval

Tags: asynchronous, state, setinterval, react-hooks, preact

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qr586w904)
Trying to `useState` inside `setInterval` of a `preact/hook`.  This isn't working, looks like for ever iteration it's executing previous callstacks(?).  Could someone help me understand and help me fix so this snippet works?

```
import {h} from 'preact';
import {useState} from 'preact/hooks'
const interests = [
  {name: 'the future',},
  {name: 'architecture',},
  {name: 'my work',},
  {name: 'your work',},
  {name: 'collaboration',},
  {name: 'dank memes',},
  {name: 'OOP vs. Functional',},
  {name: 'design',},
  {name: 'guitar',},
  {name: 'inspirational people',},
  {name: 'love',},
  {name: 'travel',},
  {name: 'singularity',},
  {name: 'creativity',},
  {name: 'mixed, virtual, augmented reality',},
  {name: 'art',},
  {name: 'imagination',},
  {name: 'problem solving',},
  {name: 'space',},
  {name: 'cooking',},
  {name: 'FOMO',},
  {name: 'ontological design',},
  {name: 'flow state',},
  {name: 'foreign languages',},
  {name: 'streaming on the internet',},
  {name: 'video games',},
  {name: 'coffee',},
  {name: 'crypto currency',},
  {name: 'javascript fatigue',},
  {name: 'framework wars',},
  {name: 'blockchain',},
  {name: 'smart contracts',},
  {name: 'just emailing me'},
  {name: 'ethereum'},
  {name: 'university'},
  {name: 'engineering software'},
];


const RunningHeader = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  setInterval(() => {setCount(c => c + 1)}, 1000);
  return (
    <header>
      <p>{interests[count].name}</p>
    </header>
)}

export {RunningHeader};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use setTimeout. setInterval is never being cancelled, so each render adds a new 1s repeating timer. Here's your sandbox fixed in 2 different ways (`setTimeout` or using `useEffect` to install the repeating timer on mount):

https://codesandbox.io/s/vy0ww725j0

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` with no dependencies `[]` will act as componentDidMount to mount our interval and we can return a function to get called on unmount, we should clear our internval on unmount to avoid memory leaks.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(() => {
    setCount(c => c + 1);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for that clarifying the `return () => clearInterval(id)`